# Create normal distribution of dates in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a distribution of dates from the vector "myvec," but my code isn't correctly working. Any suggest to create a code to generate normal distribution for 339 dates? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
myvec <- seq(as.Date('2022/01/01'), as.Date('2023/01/01'), by="day")
sample(myvec, size = 339, replace = TRUE,
   prob = c(0.2, 0.2, rep(0.1/337, 337))
   
   )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a normal-ish distribution use `rnorm`.

```
# 339 dates centered around 2022-01-01 with a sd of 10 days.
as.Date("2022-01-01") + round(rnorm(339, mean = 0, sd = 10))
```